# Trying to filter a column by name but my first result doesn't produce any data, only the following selections does

Tags: python, filter, streamlit

So I want to collect certain data for each type of catalog in my database, for example I have catalogs for GWTC, GWTC-1-confident, etc. and for each type, I need specific data such as mass_1_source, mass_2_source, etc, when I select any of the other catalogs my filter works perfectly, but when GWTC is selected, I show 0, when I know it should be 90. I can't figure out the issue.

```
def load_and_group_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("https://gwosc.org/eventapi/csv/allevents/")
    
    catalogs = ['GWTC', 'GWTC-1-confident', 'GWTC-2', 'GWTC-2.1-confident', 'GWTC-3-confident', 'O3_Discovery_Papers']
    
    grouped_data = {}
    
    for catalog in catalogs:
        event_data = df[(df['catalog.shortName'] == catalog)]
        grouped_data[catalog] = event_data

    return grouped_data

grouped_data = load_and_group_data()

# Example: Accessing specific information for an event
selected_event = st.selectbox('Select Event', grouped_data.keys())
if selected_event in grouped_data:
    event_df = grouped_data[selected_event]
    
    # Filter for 'GWTC' catalog
    if selected_event == 'GWTC':
        event_df = event_df[event_df['catalog.shortName'].str.contains('confident', case=False)]
```

I tried moving the filtering function so that it happens by default or after a user selects GWTC but it still shows up with 0 data, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I would like GWTC to be the default catalog that is loaded up before a user selects any data.

Here is my full test code if anyone wants to try it via streamlit

```
# Fetch the data from the URL and load it into a DataFrame
@st.cache_data
def load_and_group_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("https://gwosc.org/eventapi/csv/allevents/")
    
    catalogs = ['GWTC', 'GWTC-1-confident', 'GWTC-2', 'GWTC-2.1-confident', 'GWTC-3-confident', 'O3_Discovery_Papers']
    
    grouped_data = {}
    
    for catalog in catalogs:
        event_data = df[(df['catalog.shortName'] == catalog)]
        grouped_data[catalog] = event_data

    return grouped_data

grouped_data = load_and_group_data()

# Example: Accessing specific information for an event
selected_event = st.selectbox('Select Event', grouped_data.keys())
if selected_event in grouped_data:
    event_df = grouped_data[selected_event]
    
    # Filter for 'GWTC' catalog
    if selected_event == 'GWTC':
        event_df = event_df[event_df['catalog.shortName'].str.contains('confident', case=False)]
    
    st.write(f"Data for {selected_event}:")
    st.write(event_df)


count = event_df.commonName.unique().size
st.write(count)
```

Comment: Your code works just fine, are you sure of the 90 values? As i'm unable to see any for GWTC on the retrieved data/df.